# Add onclick for every image add to a post or page

Tags: wordpress, media

I want to automatically add

```
class="highslide"  onclick="return hs.expand(this,config1)"
```

to every image I add to a post or page so that I have

```
<a class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this,config1)" href="http://mysite.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/image.jpg" target="_blank"><img class="alignleft  wp-image-659" alt="" src="mysite.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/image.jpg" width="108" height="68" /></a>
```

I have looked for hrs and have found nothing that will do this, does anyone know of a plugin or a code snippet that will do this

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a little snipped for you.

```
/**
 * Function customizes a HTML code to be inserted when inserting a media file through "Add media"     button
 * @param string $insert an original HTML code to be modified
 * @return string
 */
function custom_edit_media_insert($insert)
{
    //check, whether you are inserting an image wrapped in anchor
    if(preg_match('/^(<a).*(<img).*(<\/a>$)/', $insert))
        $insert = str_replace('<a', '<a class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this,config1)"', $insert);

        return $insert;
}
add_filter('media_send_to_editor', 'custom_edit_media_insert');
```

However, I strongly engourage you to use external javascript for such purposes.

**EDIT:**

By your approach, giving every element `onclick…` code you are creating useless code. In another words, in mordern world amongst developers, you should use external javascript `<script src="script.js"></script>` and your function plate there like (via jQuery e.g.)

```
$('.parent a').click(function(){
    return hs.expand($(this),config1);
});
```

Comment: Ivan, that worked great!, and I do not understand what you saying with `use external javascript for such purposes.`

Comment: I did not mean to confuse you. I provided more info in my edit. Both ways are btw correct.

Comment: Ivan, how do I apply the java script version, I think you explained but I am not quite following it.  Thank you

Comment: How would you do this without jQuery?